# Cordova "android-release-unsigned.apk" works fine, but signed version crashes

Tags: android, cordova, crash, signing, android-keystore

My Cordova android unsigned application tested in several devices and its works perfectly. But when I signed the application for releasing using ,

```
cordova build android --release
```

Afterwards, I signed it with

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore example.keystore example.apk example

jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs example.apk

zipalign -v 4 example.apk example_01.apk
```

The signed version can be installed, but as soon as I open the app, it crashes. Anybody please guide me what is the actual issue?

My plugin list:

```
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 3.0.5 "PushPlugin"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.3.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.2 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.2.1 "Toast"
de.sitewaerts.cordova.documentviewer 0.2.0 "SitewaertsDocumentViewer"
hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.UniqueDeviceID 1.2.0 "UniqueDeviceID"
```

When I removed the push notification plugin `com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 3.0.5 "PushPlugin"` Its seems works fine. :-/

Please Help!!